# mtproto node.js sdk error reading of undefined resolve

Tags: node.js, mtproto

I get sometimes the following error:

> C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules@mtproto\core\src\rpc\index.js:548
> waitMessage.resolve(message.result);
> ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolve')
at RPC.handleDecryptedMessage (C:\C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules@mtproto\core\src\rpc\index.js:548:21)
at C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules@mtproto\core\src\rpc\index.js:469:14
at Array.forEach ()
at RPC.handleDecryptedMessage (C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules@mtproto\core\src\rpc\index.js:468:24)
at RPC.handleEncryptedMessage (C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules@mtproto\core\src\rpc\index.js:447:10)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v18.13.0

are you awaere of this and maybe working on a update?